# Functionality of PHP get_class

Tags: php

Can anyone explain why is the `get_class` function returning different values below? Specifically, what is it supposed to do when it is called in a base class and when it is called in a derived class?

```
abstract class bar {
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(get_class($this)); //prints 'foo'
        var_dump(get_class()); // prints 'bar'
    }
}

class foo extends bar {
}

new foo;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems quite well explained in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php), but here it is:

`get_class($instance)` returns the class of the `$instance` instance, regardless of where you're calling it; `get_class($this)` does behave the same way, returning the class of `$this`.

`get_class()` returns the class where the method calling it is *defined*, thus it returns `bar` in your example, as that is where `__construct()` is defined (even though you're calling it through inheritance).

Comment: You said that **'get_class()' returns the class where the method calling it is defined, thus it returns bar in your example, as that is where `__construct()` is defined (even though you're calling it through inheritance).** But if I add a `__construct` function to **foo**, like `function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }`, then? In this case, even though the `__construct` function is ultimately called in the parent class (thus it should return **bar**), that `__construct` function is itself called from within **foo**'s `__construct`. So why shouldn't it escalate to print **foo**?

Comment: Because `get_class()` is called _in_ `bar::__construct()`. It does not matter where `bar::__construct()` is called from, only where the actual invocation of `get_class()` is.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please contrast this method with the `__CLASS` way of getting the class? Both of them seem to do the same thing, although I suspect that it might not be so.

Comment: There does not seem to be any difference between the two, and both seem to be documented to return or evaluate to the same result. A possible difference is that you can pass `get_class` as a callable to methods that expect a callable, where it will be called in the context of the called method, while you can't do that with the constant, but I cannot think of a scenario where that might be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by passing `get_class` as a callable?

Comment: Actually nevermind, `call_user_func('get_class')` apparently does not work.