# Get Classname of Inherited Class when using Scope Resolution Operator (::)

Tags: php, oop, scope-resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Functionality of PHP get_class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390679/functionality-of-php-get-class)

For a small ORM-ish class-set, I have the following:

```
class Record {
  //Implementation is simplified, details out of scope for this question.
  static public function table() {
    return strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', get_class()))."s";
  }

  static public function find($conditions) {
    //... db-selection calls go here.
    var_dump(self::table());
  }
}

class Payment extends Record {
}

class Order extends Record {
  public $id = 12;
  public function payments() {
    $this->payments = Payment::find(array('order_id', $this->id, '='));
  }
}

$order = new Order();
$order->payments();
#=> string(7) "records"
```

I would *expect* this code to print:

```
#=> string(8) "payments"
```

But, instead, it prints `records`. I have tried `self::table()`, but that gives the same result.

**Edit, after some questions in the comments** `table()` is a method that simply maps the name of the Class to the table in wich its objects live: `Order` lives in `orders`, `Payment` lives in `payments`; `records` *does not exist!*). When I call `Payments::find()`, I expect it to search on the table `payments`, not on the table `records`, nor on the table `orders`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the classname of the class on which ::is called, instead of the class in which is was defined?

Important part is probably the `get_class()`, not being able to return the proper classname.

Comment: @lanzz: no, but it is very much related to [get classname from static call in extended class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/php-get-classname-from-static-call-in-extended-class?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your call is static, since your method is incorrectly declared as not static.

Comment: lanzz: yes. Will edit that. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Referencing `$this` in a static method is an error (in your `Payment::find` method).

Comment: Lanzz: thanks. I edited without compiling/running. Changed to reflect the static-declarations in my last edit.

Comment: Calling `self::table()` destroys whatever inheritance context you might have had, as `self` always points to the class you have _defined_ the method in, not the one that has inherited it. Perhaps `static::table()` might do? But still, `get_class()` without argument is defined to also return the class the calling method is defined in, not the LSB one.

Comment: @lanzz: got it! `static::table()` and then `get_called_class()` did the trick. If you make it an answer, I can accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [get_called_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) if you're using php 5.3 or higher. It gives you the class the static method is called on, not the one where the method is actually defined.

**UPDATE**

You need the class name of the class on which 'find' is called. You can fetch the class name in the find method and provide it as a parameter to the table (maybe rename it to getTableForClass($class)) method. get_called_class will give you the Payment class, the table method derives the table name and returns it:

```
class Record {
    //Implementation is simplified, details out of scope for this question.
    static public function getTableForClass($class) {
        return strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', $class))."s";
    }

    static public function find($conditions) {
        //... db-selection calls go here.
        $className = get_called_class();
        $tableName = self::getTableForClass($class);

        var_dump($tableName);
    }
 }
```

Comment: When changing to get_called_class() as explained on [PHPs docs on late static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php), I now get `orders`. Whereas I want `records`.

Comment: In your question you say you don't expect 'records' but 'payments'. I'm not sure what you want now. :) You can use `__CLASS__` if you need it to print 'Records'.

Comment: table() is a method that simply maps the name of the Class to the table in wich its objects live (Order lives in orders, Payment, lives in payments; records does not exist!). When I call Payments::find(), I expect it to search on the table "payments", not on the table "records", nor on the table "orders"). Will add that to the question to clarify it. Thanks